# In this situation, is there a relation between x and y that is always true regardless of the values of the other variables involved?

Tags: proof-verification

The situation:  $$x=\frac ab\quad \& \quad y=\frac a{b+c}$$

[(Image here, won't allow me to post images because of my low reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhRFm.png)

Comment: If $x=a/b$ and $y=a/(b+c)$, then what?

Comment: Well, obviously $\frac 1y=\frac 1x+\frac ca$, at least when $a\neq 0$.  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands, I have no idea what you are asking.  You tag to "proof verification" which would suggest that you have a proof you would like verified....yet no proof (nor even statement) appears in the post.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

As $x=\frac{a}{b}$, we get $a=bx$. So, we have -
\begin{align}
y&=\frac{bx}{b+c}\\
&=\frac{x}{1+\frac{c}{b}}\\
&=\frac{x}{1+k}\\
\end{align}
for $k=\frac{c}{b}$.

Thus, the relation between $x$ and $y$ always depends at least on one constant.